# require 'mysql',No such file to load -- mysql in ROR development serevr but working when running as ruby application

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection

Hi I am a newbie to Ruby on rails

when I try to access Mysql database manually in Ruby on rails development server,I get a **No such file to load -- mysql** at  line require 'mysql',but when I try to run the same code as a ruby application,it does not throw any error and connects to DB.

I have searched a lot about this but couldn't solve the issue.

and Yes I have already installed mysql through gem and already put libmysql.ddl in my ruby/bin folder.
my ruby version is 1.9.3

Please Help ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have some code to show? People can;t help without any code.

Comment: Which MySQL driver do you have loaded in your `Gemfile`? You should probably be using the `mysql2` one.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,I have solved the problem.The issue was that I did not update my gemfile and also in my database.yml ,I have put db/databaseName (which is fine with sqllite3) but with mysql direct database should have been given it seems.